# NextJS production build fails to run with 'npm run start' due to missing src/utils folder

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, nx-workspace

I'm working on an Nx workspace with a NextJS application, and I'm having trouble running the production build using npm run start. After building the app with `nx run app:build:production`, I try to run the application inside the dist directory using the command `npm run start`, but I get an error saying **"Failed to load next.config.js. Error: Cannot find module '../src/utils/config'.**"

The issue seems to be related to a missing **src/utils** folder, which is required by the with-nx.js file that is generated during the build process. However, when I checked my project directory, I couldn't find any folders named src or utils.

Strangely, the production build runs without any issues when using `nx run app:serve:production` command or deployed into **vercel**.

Can anyone help me understand why the src/utils folder is missing and how I can resolve this issue so that I can run the production build with npm run start command?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to upgrade Nx to 16.1.3 (from 16.1.2) and NextJS to 13.4.1 (from 13.3.4) including of course the culprit @nx/next to 16.1.3 as well.

I have been struggling for a few days with what seems to be the same problem. I saw this problem when building an image with Docker where only the node_modules from the dist/apps/myapp/package.json were installed inside the image (with RUN npm install inside the Dockerfile).

The "dist/app" folder included the file .nx-helpers/with-nx.js that would require "../src/utils/config" which was NOT included in dist/app. Looking in with-nx.js the following was found:

```
const config_1 = require("../src/utils/config");
...

function withNx(_nextConfig = {}, context = getWithNxContext()) {
// If this is not set user will see compile errors in Next.js 13.4.
// See: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/16692, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49169
// TODO(jack): Remove this once Nx is refactored to invoke CLI directly.
(0, config_1.forNextVersion)('>=13.4.0', () => {
```

This has indeed been refactored now in Nx 16.1.3 that was released only 13 hours ago (I think this is the issue https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/16867).

Comment: Thank you for the insights. Will have a look